# The 'OraOLEDB.Oracle' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, debug, connectionstring

estou com um problema que me está a limitar o trabalho, é o seguinte, criei um *WebService* com uma `connection string` para uma base de dados em oracle :

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Persist Security Info=False;DATA SOURCE=********;USER ID=******;Password=*******");
```

Os (*)'s são para esconder a informação, de qualquer das maneiras quando corro o programa para correr a minha `query` dá-me este erro:

> "The 'OraOLEDB.Oracle1' provider is not registered on the local
>   machine"

Conseguem explicar-me o porquê ?
Eu tenho o Oracle instalado no computador e já coloquei o Target CPU em x64 e x86 e de nada resolveu.

Comment: Para tentar ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

Comment: Ele está a usar Ace.Oledb e não Oracle, o erro é diferente, mas obrigado de qualquer das maneiras ! :)

Comment: Saquei, e esse link aqui: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/79350e20-35b1-4f01-9f2c-929b8247e83b/o-provedor-oraoledboracle-no-est-registrado-na-mquina-local?forum=504

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa registrar o driver OLEDB:

1 - Verifique a pasta que contém o arquivo `OraOLEDB11.dll`. ('oracle\product\11.2.0\client_64\BIN')

2 - Abra o cmd como administrador

3 - Navegue até a pasta onde contém a DLL. Ex: `cd\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_64\BIN`

4 - Execute o registro:

```
regsvr32 OraOLEDB11.dll
```

Se não houver a DLL no seu computador, deve estar faltando a instalação do `Oracle Client`

Comment: Tentei fazer isso e não resultou, uma coisa, o meu bin estava numa pasta chamada server e não "Client_64"

Comment: tente colocar essa dll dentro da pasta system32 ou syswow64