# Erro: O provedor 'ORAOLEDB.Oracle' não está registrado na máquina local

Tags: c#, oracle, windows-10, oracle12c

Erro: O provedor 'ORAOLEDB.Oracle' não está registrado na máquina local.

Estou precisando fazer algumas manutenções em um projeto .NET , com a versão do Oracle 12c e meu sistema operacional é Windows 10 Education de 64bits. Estou encontrando esse erro

> O provedor 'ORAOLEBD.Oracle' não está registrado na máquina local.

Essas foram as seguintes tentativas que realizei encontradas na internet:

1. **comando via CMD:** cd C:\app\client\User\product\12.2.0\client_1\bin
   c:\Windows\system32\regsvr32.exe OraOLEDB12.dll Na tentativa de
   fazer o registro manual, porem não tive sucesso ele ainda continua
   apresentando o erro.
2. Já desinstalei o Oracle e instalei novamente.
3. Fiz configurações nas "variáveis de ambiente" no meu sistema
       operacional.
4. Mudei o "alvo da plataforma" para x64 e x86 no BUILD dentro da
   plataforma .NET  Instalei o Oracle Client "Administrator"
5. Instalei via comando CMD a pasta ODAC122010Xcopy_x64

Foram essas as soluções que encontrei e nenhuma resolveu meu caso.

Comment: Você verificou se tem o client 64 bits instalado em outra pasta? Se sim, registrou ele?

Comment: Sim, já verifiquei isso e também eu registrei ele via CMD para ter certeza e mesmo assim ele continuo com o mesmo erro

Answer (score 1):

Geralmente o problema é só a falta de registro mesmo. Inclusive já existe [respostas no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/215917/35358) que resolve esse mesmo problema.

A solução padrão costuma ser os passos abaixo, conforme resposta que linkei:

1. Abra o prompt de comando como administrador
2. Execute: `cd \oracle\product\11.2.0\client_64\BIN` (Ou o caminho que está seu cliente 64 bits)
3. `c:\Windows\system32\regsvr32.exe OraOLEDB11.dll`

> Certifique-se de abrir o CMD como administrador.

Mas como você falou que já fez isso pra ambos os clients e não teve sucesso, faça as verificações listadas abaixo:

1. Para o **Windows 7** ou **Windows 10** tente seguir os mesmos passos
   informados anteriormente mas utilizando o caminho
   `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Regsvr32.exe` para o **passo 3**.
2. Use o trecho abaixo para identificar se sua aplicação está rodando a
   64 ou 32 bits e tente alternar entre um e outro após registrar o
   **OraOLEDB11.dll**.

   ```
   if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("64 Bits!");
   }
   else
   {
       Console.WriteLine("32 Bits!");
   }
   ```
3. Verifique a [variável de ambiente](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-EC18C4A6-3BA5-4C14-9D76-B0DD62FEFFF2.htm#ADMQS12369) **PATH** e se existe nela o
   caminho do cliente 32 ou 64 e tente alternar entre eles e testar a
   aplicação.

Já tive esse mesmo problema em uma aplicação (mas com oracle 11g), e no meu caso a instalação usando o [XCopy_64bits](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html) que resolveu o problema. Caso nada disso solucione seu caso já que a maioria você já tentou, considere tentar novamente com a instalação do xcopy.

Tentei dar bastante detalhe na resposta, por que boa parte das soluções conhecidas você informou que já tentou fazer, mas muito provável que uma delas que vá resolver seu problema. Talvez em uma dessas opções tenha faltado algum detalhe.